# Why does memtest show two DIMM1 locations?

Tags: memtest86+

I was troubleshooting some problems with my laptop memory, and I saw something weird in the DMI information popup:

[image: DMI Memory Device Info]

Is that a bug in memtest, or do I have a problem with my laptop's hardware?

Comment: no way to tell for sure, but yes that looks like a typo/bug.

Comment: Does this same error appear in UEFI? I am pretty sure Memtest86 would be getting the information from the hardware ( in order to support 2,4,6,8 DIMM slots ).

Comment: Sadly, the UEFI settings only show that I have 16GB of memory available, nothing else. It's an "InsydeH20" firmware.